# How to parse JSON String in Java to get String anotherJSON which is contained inside

Tags: java, json

I am getting `String jsonObject` in my controller. 
The structure is following:

```
{
  "name":"name", 
  "schema": {
   ... 
   ...
   }
}
```

I need to parse it into a Plain Old Java Object and receive `schema` as a String (saving the structure). When I am using `System.out.print("schema")`, I expect to see:

```
{
  ...
  ... 
}
```

I have a POJO `Collection` with `String name` and `Object schema` fields.
I am using GSON to get `Collection.class` from `String json`:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, Collection.class);
```

When I try to print `Collection.schema` I get the following output:

`{......}` - in a one row.

I really need to get this object as a `String` **without formatting**

Comment: So are you asking for a way have the value of "schema" not be decoded, but somehow preserved as the original string of characters that represented it in the original JSON?  I guess you'd want the "schema" key's value to be that string.  Seems like a strange thing to want.  If you re-encoded such a structure, you'd get a different JSON string than the original.

Comment: Yes. How can I get string of characters that represented it in the original JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Basically, you hydrate your Collection object and then just send your schema back through Gson. Done.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection collection = gson.fromJson(json, Collection.class);
String schema = gson.toJson(collection.getSchema());
System.out.println(schema);
```

Question could be asked as to why you are accepting a String from your controller? Perhaps you can get the framework you are using to pass in a fully converted Collection object and save yourself a step?

Also, for your Collection.schema, it's common to use `Map<String, Object>` instead of Object for this type of "schema"-less type of paradigm.

Comment: I am only getting started to write REST services using Spring Boot. I would be happy if you can advice me how i can do it better

Comment: Ah yes, then Spring REST will do this. So in your controller method arguments, just use   ```yourMethod(@RequestBody Collection collection)```. Then from there you can use GSON to convert the schema to a json String.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Spring Web REST. Hope you have fun in your journey.